# The Stackoverflow Guessing Game: get random question title and guess site it belongs to

Tags: discussion, feature-request, fun

Despite the very low fraction of actually *fun* questions on Stack Exchange, one can have considerable fun by browsing through arbitrary cross-site question titles. Some question titles are *quite* weird out of context. For example:

- *How does one become a god?* was *not* asked on Christianity.
- *Dealing with curly brace soup*, (displayed next to a picture of a cup of coffee), was *not* asked on Seasoned Advice.
- *Why aren't the characters floating two levels down?* was *not* asked on Physics.
- *How can I tell if a corpse is safe to eat?* was asked *neither* on Seasoned Advice, *nor* on *The Great Outdoors*.
- *My head keeps falling off. What can I do?* was *not* asked on Biology (and I guess medical advice is not on-topic anyway).
- *Why did the humans leave their original planet to found the colonies?* was *not* asked on History.
- ...etcetera.

I think one could design a quite fun game where players need to guess where certain questions belong. It probably would be most-fun with multiple-choice questions that are hand-picked, but possibly even with random questions some hilarious examples would come along occasionally!

Is there any way to get a list of cross-site random questions? The closest I know are "hot questions" and *filtered questions*, which are cross-site but not random.

Comment: [Not a real question – A Stack Exchange game](http://notarealquestion.appspot.com/)

Comment: @YannisRizos looks fun. Not exactly the same, and doesn't seem to include the beta sites. But thanks for the pointer :)

Comment: RPG, Programmers, Movies, Arqade, Arqade, SF&F - What do I win? ;P

Comment: Here's a similar game you can play: Think up a legitimate and plausible question such that a straightforward descriptive title would sound bizarre yet possibly relevant on as many other sites as possible. (Overly contrived titles or questions that would get closed on their intended site don't count.)

Comment: @Yannis - solved in 9.07 seconds?????